# Can Wait By Attribute honour the dynamic dates in Journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, date, loop

I have a '**Wait by Attribute**' in my Journey which is referring to a date attribute in a data extension from contact builder. I then have a SQL criteria to change the Date values based on certain business rules.

I am expecting the **Wait by Attribute** to honour the new updated date values instead of the one it was referring to initially when contact made it to this **Wait by Attribute** activity.

The documentation on this activity is limited and doesn't explain much. Is this possible? if not, is there a way to handle this scenario in Journey?

Thanks,
Mano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the attribute you're using as the basis for your Wait By Attribute activity is within your "Journey Data", the value is immutable and no update to the underlying Journey Entry Data Extension done with SQL after injection would be taken into consideration by the activities within the Journey. If the attribute you're using is taken from your "Contact Data", updates to the field in question are reflected as the contact progresses through the Journey.

Once the contact has entered the wait, the date and time of exit is fixed. In other words, updating the field used by your Wait by Attribute will have no effect on when the contact exits the wait.

Comment: Thank you @Macca. This is helpful.

Comment: I used Contact Data and still, Wait By Attribute Activity takes tha value, which were in Data Extension, on journey activation. I asked my question here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/416648/wait-by-attribute-in-2-way-sms-communication-journey-values-in-the-field-chang