# Wait By Attribute in 2-way SMS communication journey - values in the field changed by next keyword

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sms, sendsmsactivity

I am trying to prepare a journey for 2-way SMS conversation, on the basis of this topic: [Capture SMS response on Journey Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296800/capture-sms-response-on-journey-builder). So my journey sends SMS message to the consumer and on the basis what consumer replies, I will reply with different messages.

[image: Journey - version 6]

Entry Data Extensions contains only columns for SubscriberKey and phone number (but I don't see any issue with adding new columns if needed).

Next I created two Data Extensions:

- *Identity_test*, which contains *SubscriberKey* and *Mobile_Number*
- *Survey_response*, with fields *MobileNumber* (PK), *Response* and *response_date* (both nullable)

Then in Data Designer, I created new Attribute group, where I linked *Identity_test* to Customer Data (1:1 Contact Key to SubscriberKey). And next I linked *Survey_response* to *Identity_test* (1:1 Mobile_Number to MobileNumber).

First Activity in the journey is SMS *First_survey_SMS_20240202* with this code:

```
%%[
UpsertData('Survey_response', 1, 'MobileNumber', MOBILE_NUMBER, 'response_date', '2030-01-01')
]%%
How do you rate our service in the scale from 0 to 10?
```

This SMS Activity uses next keyword, which is associated with the message with this Ampscript (prepared on the basis, what Eliot shared in the post mentioned above):

```
%%[
var @response, @validResponse
set @response = [MSG(0).NOUNS]
set @now = Now()
UpsertData('Survey_response', 1, 'MobileNumber', MOBILE_NUMBER, 'Response', @response, 'response_date', @now)
]%%
```

Message contains only Ampscript, so the consumer will receive nothing (which is desirable behaviour), but the response will be upserted to Data Extension *Survey_response*. So I know if, in next SMS, I need to ask why the rating was high, or what was wrong with our services (if grade was low).

And now why I'm playing with *response_date* column in both SMS messages - *First_survey_SMS_20240202* and the one associated with next keyword? And where is my problem?

Because in my journey, I put Wait By Attribute Activity, where I check value in the table *Survey_response*, in the field *response_date*. I'm doing it, becuase I want the consumer will go to the next step of the journey, soon after replied to us (but correct me if I'm wrong, and I can do it in totally different way).

But from my observations, how the journey behaves now: when, **on journey activation**,  *response_date* is empty (e.g. when for the given consumer, there is no record in *Survey_response* table), then consumer directly goes to the next Activity - Decision Split, and lands in the Remainder (so I can still capture the rate, which consumer will send to us, but I will not be able to reply for the rating, as consumer is already on the exit). It doesn't matter, that in *First_survey_SMS_20240202*, I'm updating *response_date* to 2030-01-01 - journey seems to look only at the value, which existed on activation.

Then, when I manually put a record in *Survey_response*, with *response_date* in the future (e.g. 2032-01-01), and activated new version, journey waits (you can see it on my screenshot for Version 6). And when consumer replied to us with the response "5" on the date "Friday, February 02, 2024 5:24 PM", then both values are correctly upserted into the table *Survey_response*, to columns *Response* and *response_date*. But journey still waits and I believe will be waiting until 2032-01-01. It doesn't matter, that consumer replied on "Friday, February 02, 2024 5:24 PM" and I want to continue conversation after that.

This topic: [Can Wait By Attribute honour the dynamic dates in Journey?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/319783/can-wait-by-attribute-honour-the-dynamic-dates-in-journey) says, that if I want to dynamically change the dates, used by Wait By Attribute Activity, I need to use Contact Data, not Journey Data. And I believe, this is exatly, what I'm doing.

What is wrong with my approach? How can I have SMS conversation with the consumer, on the basis of consumer's replies?

Comment: Your first SMS creates a record in Survey Response DE setting the response_date to "2030-01-01" and then the user moves on the the wait by duration that would read this value and put the contact into a wait for the next six years. Sounds like you're probably needing to use a Wait Until activity https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_wait_until_api_event.htm&type=5 that listens for the firing of an API event by your Next Keyword Response.